# Phase Angle: AC Circuit

Tags: waves, electric-circuits

I am seeing this everywhere when I look up impedance and reactance for AC circuits. Below is a picture below from the website [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phase-difference.html).

[image]

They say the formula for the phase angle is $y=\sin(\omega t+\phi)$. I don't think this is correct to say because you can't just shift the graph over $\phi$ from here. You have to pull out the value for $\omega$ as shown below.

> If we were to use this formula, shouldn't the middle graph be $y=A_m\sin(\omega(t+\phi))$? I go through and derive this formula here at 15 minutes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS9E0n_5m9g&t=1416s) as to how this formula works; I write it a little differently. For example,
> the graph in red is $y=1\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3} t+0.9)$ and the graph in black is $y=1\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}( t+0.9))$ where it is indeed shifted to the left $0.9$ units which means you can't represent the phase angle at the end like that. What am I missing? I am plotting $y$ on the $y$-axis and $t$ on the horizontal axis.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the way you describe it, it's just not the convention.

It would not be unreasonable to write the equation as $y=\
sin(\omega (t + \tau))$.  In this case, I choose $\tau$ rather than $\phi$ as a convention.  In your formulation, you are adding a time, rather than an angle.  $\phi$ is conventionally an angle while $\tau$ is conventionally a time.  Obviously changing variable names doesn't change the equation in the slightest, but it does help readability.  Switching names also lets me write the obvious equation: $\phi = \omega\tau$.  That relationship converts a time constant into a phase angle.  And, like others have mentioned, it keeps the units correct.

While $\phi$ and $\tau$ are obviously exchangeable, using the above relationship, we typically choose to use $\phi$.  The phase angle turns out to be a more practically useful concept than $\tau$ is.  With a single frequency, it's six of one, half a dozen of the other.  But later, as you work with more complex signals with more frequencies, $\phi$ turns out to be a more useful tool for analyzing the behavior of circuits.

Now, that all being said, you did ask about the pictures.  And I believe you are correct that they are missing a term.  Because the x axis is time, all angles such as $\phi$ need a constant to convert them into times: $\frac 1 \omega$.  The picture shows a shift of $\phi$, when they really should show $\frac \phi \omega$  It would have been more technically precise for them to label that x-axis $\theta$, indicating that it is an angle.  Then values such as $\phi$ , $\pi + \phi$, and $\pi - \phi$ would all be technically correct.

Comment: This makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing?

You are missing the units. The term $\omega t$ is an angle so $\phi$ must also be an angle in order to add $\omega t+ \phi$.

Your expression $\omega(t+\phi)$ is dimensionally inconsistent. You cannot add a time and a phase.

One potential source of this confusion is that the horizontal axis of your plot is not labeled. It is time, not angle. So you should not expect that a phase angle shift is directly used there. You have to convert the phase to a time to determine the amount of time to shift. So let $\Delta t=\phi/\omega$ which gives $\omega t + \phi =\omega(t+\Delta t)$ which is dimensionally consistent.

It is always good practice to label your axes and to check your units.

Comment: Here $\omega$ is radians per second, $t$ is seconds, and $\phi$ is an angle measured in radians. Here I am plotting $t$ in seconds on the $x$-axis. Why are we converting the phase angle to a time? Why does $\phi = \omega \Delta t$? And how does that give $\omega (t +\Delta t)$ because those aren't equal?

Comment: @WilliamGarske asked “Why are we converting the phase angle to a time?” Your horizontal axis is time, so if you want to find out how much to shift horizontally then the quantity you use must have units of time. I edited my answer to address the other questions

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Red graph - crosses the time axis at $t=-0.43\,\rm s$
$\omega = \frac {2\pi}{3}$ radians per second, thus a time of $0.43\,\rm s$ represents an angle $\phi = \frac {2\pi}{3} \times 0.43=0.9\,\rm radians$

Black graph - crosses the time axis at $t=-0.9\,\rm s$
$\omega = \frac {2\pi}{3}$ radians per second, thus a time of $0.9\,\rm s$ represents an angle $\phi = \frac {2\pi}{3} \times 0.9=1.9\,\rm radians$

So to be dimensional correct the bracket is $(\underbrace{\omega\,t}_{\rm radian} + \underbrace{\phi}_{\rm radian})$